# Блок при масштабировании накладывается на блок сверху

Tags: html, css

При масштабировании блок `dash` накладывается на блок сверху:

```css
.myWorks {
  margin-top: 71px;
  height: 234px;
  position: relative;
}

.myWorks .row {
  width: 100%;
}

.myWorks1 img {
  position: relative;
}

.myWorks .myWorksH3 {
  /* Style for "Check Out" */
  color: #464646;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.myWorks p {
  margin-top: 33px;
  color: #414141;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.TwoWorks {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}

.FindOut a {
  color: #474747;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.FindOut a:hover {
  color: #474747;
}

.myLatestWork {
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 430px;
  position: relative;
}

.dash {
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 0;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(120deg, #c9c9c9, #c9c9c9 1px, transparent 1.4px, transparent 3px);
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.dash h4 {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 28px;
  padding-right: 28px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.works {
  margin-top: 58px;
  height: 285px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="myWorks">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="TwoWorks col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          <div class="myWorks1">
            <img src="img/magnify-glass.jpg" alt="Glass" align="left">
            <h3 class="myWorksH3">Check Out our latest <br> projects</h3>
            <p>Maecenas ipsum metus, semper hendrerit varius mattis, congue sit amet tellus. Aliquam ullamcorper dui sed magna posue re ut elementum enim rutrum. Nam mi erat, porta id ultrices nec, pellentesque vel nunc. Cras varius fermentum iaculis. Aenean
              sodales nibh non lectus tempor a interdum justo ultricies.</p>
            <p class="FindOut"><a href="#">find out more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="TwoWorks col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          <div class="myWorks2">
            <img src="img/star.jpg" alt="Start" align="left">
            <h3 class="myWorksH3">Guarantee 5 star <br> Quality Work</h3>
            <p>Maecenas ipsum metus, semper hendrerit varius mattis, congue sit amet tellus. Aliquam ullamcorper dui sed magna posue re ut elementum enim rutrum. Nam mi erat, porta id ultrices nec, pellentesque vel nunc. Cras varius fermentum iaculis. Aenean
              sodales nibh non lectus tempor a interdum justo ultricies.</p>
            <p class="FindOut"><a href="#">find out more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          <div class="myWorks3">
            <img src="img/dialog.jpg" alt="Dialog" align="left">
            <h3 class="myWorksH3">Stay connected by <br> reading the blog</h3>
            <p>Maecenas ipsum metus, semper hendrerit varius mattis, congue sit amet tellus. Aliquam ullamcorper dui sed magna posue re ut elementum enim rutrum. Nam mi erat, porta id ultrices nec, pellentesque vel nunc. Cras varius fermentum iaculis. Aenean
              sodales nibh non lectus tempor a interdum justo ultricies.</p>
            <p class="FindOut"><a href="#">find out more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="myLatestWork">
      <div class="dash col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <h4>My latest work</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что я задал высоту для myWorks